# Declare class namespace in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Project H_Pro. There is a user control `logistic`. In logistic, I have a class `GroupingName`. How i can declare logistic namespace in `logistic` xaml and then use this `GroupingName` class ?

I'm tyring to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388138/wpf-datagrid-group-expander-text-how-to-bind) but I cannot.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have a class in a user control? Is it some kind of nested class?

Comment: yes... please stackoverflow link which in my question

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware you cannot use nested classes in XAML.